# Create and place an image where the user taps

Tags: java, android

I have a empty frame layout, when the user taps the screen in a certain area, I want to place an image exactly where he pressed. So far I was able to get the coordinates of the press but I'm not quite able to create a new image (simple .png red circle) and place it inside the frame layout at the spot the user tapped.

This is the code far, 'ultimoToque[]' holds the X and Y value for a tap inside the frame layout.

```
private boolean editMode = true;
private float[] ultimoToque = new float[2];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph_maker);

    View myView = findViewById(R.id.graph_space);
    myView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);

    // IF editMode is true AND last tap is inside frame layout
        // THEN place red circle at position defined by ultimoToque[]
}

View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ultimoToque[0] = event.getX();
            ultimoToque[1] = event.getY();
        }

        double x = ultimoToque[0];
        double y = ultimoToque[1];

        Log.i("TAG", "Novas coordenadas x: " + x + ", y: " + y);

        return false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to place a new image on each tap or move the same image to a new position.

To place a new image

Make `myView` global

```
private boolean editMode = true;
private float[] ultimoToque = new float[2];
private RelativeLayout myView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph_maker);

    myView = findViewById(R.id.graph_space);
    myView.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
}
```

Use this function to add a new image

```
private void addNewImage(double X, double Y) {
    ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourimage);
    myView.addView(img);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) img.getLayoutParams();
    lParams.leftMargin = (int)X;
    lParams.topMargin = (int)Y;
    img.setLayoutParams(lParams);
}
```

Call this function like this

```
View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ultimoToque[0] = event.getX();
            ultimoToque[1] = event.getY();
        }

        double x = ultimoToque[0];
        double y = ultimoToque[1];
        addNewImage(x, y)
        Log.i("TAG", "Novas coordenadas x: " + x + ", y: " + y);

        return false;
    }
};
```

For moving the same image to a new position just make the new image global and change it's `leftMargin` and `topMargin` values.

If you want to set your circle centred on touch coordinates, just decrement the half of image width and height to top and left values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but .addView(img) is not working. Maybe I'm missing something? My image is a .png 50x50px, it that what img.setImageResource(R.drawable.-->yourimage<--) should receive?

Comment: Yes, put the name of your image instead of `yourimage`.

Comment: I'm getting an error: "cannot find symbol method addView(ImageView)". Do you know why is that?

Comment: I was able to fix by changing the View to RelativeLayout and the red circle appear on screen centralized where I tapped, thanks a lot

Comment: Ok, yes you need a to set or cast `myView` as `RelativeLayout`. Edited my answer in case of someone else needs it.